# Add Padding to Sub Menu Items in CSS Horizontal Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

How can I add some padding-left: 5px; to all of my sub menu items. How can the CSS coding be modified below to do the trick?

```
/*HORIZONTAL DROP-DOWN MENU */   
#menu{
padding:0;
margin:0;
position: fixed;
top: 30px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 8pt;
}
#menu ul{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#menu li{
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
} 

#menu li a{
width:120px;
height: 20px;
display: block;
text-decoration:none;
line-height: 20px;
background-color: #A9BBD3;
color: #FFF;
} 

#menu li a:hover{
background-color: #446087;
} 

#menu ul ul{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
}
#menu > ul > li > a{
    text-align:center;
}


<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">File</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">Save</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Edit</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#nogo">View</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

jsfiddle.net/MP5km/2/

Just added this css:

```
#menu li li a { padding-left: 5px; width:115px; }
```

Comment: Works great! I guess there are more ways to skin a cat then just one in the world of css =\. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your CSS :

```
#menu ul ul li a {
    width: 115px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JQsf6/1/).

Comment: Works great too. Thanks again for everyones help. Love that you guys are on here. Thanks for your knowlege and time.